# Image outline points generator?

Tags: java, c++, matlab, opengl, jogl

Is there any code(specifically Java or C++) or software in which we import any image and it gives the outline of that image in points, which we can use again to draw image outline by joining those points in JOGL or OPenGL ..

Comment: @amro if i can get a code in MATLAB, it will also help :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an outline tracer in Inkscape (which is open source c++).

http://inkscape.org/doc/tracing/tutorial-tracing.html

This will convert to vector format - so you could get some points out this way.

EDIT: this actually uses http://potrace.sourceforge.net/ for the tracing..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code in MATLAB:

```
%# read image
I = imread('coins.png');

%# Convert to a binary image
BW = im2bw(I, graythresh(I));

%# get object boundaries
BW = imfill(BW,'holes');
B = bwboundaries(BW,'noholes');

%# plot boundaries overlayed on top of image
imshow(I), hold on
for i=1:numel(B)
    plot(B{i}(:,2), B{i}(:,1), 'Color','g', 'LineWidth',2)
end
hold off
```

[image]